# How to handle all signals in GDB

Tags: gdb

I am doing to following:

```
gdb -p $progid -x $file


>> cat file
>> handle SIGUSR1 nostop
    c
```

How can I handle all signals to nostop without having to write:

```
handle SIGUSR1 nostop
handle SIGUSR2 nostop
Etc...
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
handle all nostop
```

Further documentation: [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20221228155940/https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html).

Comment: And you might also want `set pagination off` to not make GDB stop, as the output list will be long: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815621/how-to-disable-type-return-to-continue-or-q-return-to-quit-in-gdb