# gdb (MinGW) doesn't break on failed asserts (VSCode config)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, gdb, mingw

I'm trying to debug a program, in VSCode, which violates an assert, but doesn't break and doesn't allow me to inspect the callstack or anything. Instead the program just exits with exitcode 3 and prints out the following text:

```
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Users\Sewbacca\Projects\Practice\CppTest\build\Test.exe
File: C:\Users\Sewbacca\Projects\Practice\CppTest\src\main.cpp, Line 6

Expression: false
```

I tried to add the following commands to `"setupCommands"` in `.vscode/launch.json` with no success:

```json
{
    "text": "break _assert (const char *_Message, const char *_File, unsigned _Line)"
},
{
    "text": "break abort"
},
{
    "text": "break exit"
},
```

Sidenote: I'm not experienced with gdb and I don't know exactly what setupCommands does change. I would have expected that vscode send these to gdb directly.

My only workarround is to set a breakpoint before `main()` and type `-exec break abort` into the debug console. Then it will break on any failed asserts.

Edit:
Adding the following config to `"setupCommands"`:

```
{
    "text": "-exec break abort"
},
```

Resulted in following error message:

```
[Window Title]
Visual Studio Code

[Content]
Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec break abort". Undefined MI command: exec

[Open 'launch.json'] [Cancel]
```

End of Edit

Is there a way to automate this or is there a proper way to tell gdb (especially in VSCode) to break on failed asserts, rather than just exit the program?

Edit:

There was nothing wrong with my configuration. It seems like my gdb version was buggy. Sometimes it exited randomly when I told gdb to break before entering main, which led me to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5889). As stated there, gdb 8.1 for x86_64-w64-mingw32 has this bug. Since there is no newer version available in [the installer](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds), I downgraded to 7.2 which solved this issue for me. However, after using [winlibs](https://winlibs.com/) version 11.1.0, the issue still persists.

End of edit

Thanks in advance!

##### Setup:

`src/main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    assert(false);
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
project(Test)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
```

`.vscode/launch.json`

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            // Resolved by CMake Tools:
            "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [
                {
                    // add the directory where our target was built to the PATHs
                    // it gets resolved by CMake Tools:
                    "name": "PATH",
                    "value": "${env:PATH}:${command:cmake.getLaunchTargetDirectory}"
                }
            ],
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "text": "break _assert (const char *_Message, const char *_File, unsigned _Line)"
                },
                {
                    "text": "break abort"
                },
                {
                    "text": "break exit"
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
    "compounds": []
}
```

My Environment:

- Platform: Windows 10
- Toolchain: mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0
- Build system: CMake
- IDE: VSCode with extension CMake Tools

Comment: Since you type `-exec break abort` into the debug console, I would also expect the same to work in your configuration.

Comment: I attempted this, but forgot to put it into the post. It has been now added. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

`gdb` breaks on failed asserts, when adding the following code to `setupCommands` in `launch.json`:

```json
"setupCommands": {
...
    {
        "text": "set breakpoint pending on",
        "description": "Ensures that a breakpoint for abort will be set!",
        "ignoreFailures": true
    },
    {
        "text": "break abort",
        "description": "Breaks on failed asserts",
        "ignoreFailures": true
    },
    {
        "text": "set breakpoint pending auto",
        "description": "Setting back to default behaviour",
        "ignoreFailures": true
    }
...
}
```

Explaination:

To break on assert failures, I found this [Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646862/what-is-the-proper-way-to-break-on-failed-asserts-in-gdb), which worked, when I tested it manually, but not when I used it in `launch.json`.
I don't understand why it doesn't break on its own, but I do understand why `break abort` didn't worked, at least I have a guess: The symbols haven't been loaded yet and `break abort` asks you in `gdb`, if a pending breakpoint should be created, which defaults to no. So setting pending breakpoints to on, solved this issue for me and now I can finally debug my program.